# how we can check if all the div are displayed none

Tags: html, jquery

I want to show message like NO result found if all div are set display none

```
element.each(function(i, el) {
    if (all element set display:none) {
        no result found
    }
}
```

```
<div class="a" data-key="a" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="a" data-key="a" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="a" data-key="a" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="a" data-key="a" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="a" data-key="c" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="a" data-key="c" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Who (which function) is responsible for hiding them? That function should know if there's no result. Just add the _"no results found"_ there.

Comment: if($(".a").is(":hidden")) should check all div with class 'a' is hidden or not

Comment: @ssilas777 I always (incorrectly) assume that `.is()` only applies to first element, as otherwise it should be called `.are()` - **however** - from jquery docs:  *Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.* - so it's not `.is()` or `.are()` but it's **actually** `.any()`  (not `.all()` which is what would be required here)  I guess `$(".a").is(":not(:hidden)")` might handle it or (from @Andreas 's link) `!$(".a").is(":visible")`

Answer (score 0):

A very quick example in vanilla JavaScript below selects the `divs` in your code example, and puts them in an array using `querySelectorAll` with   `class name` selector.

The `areAllDivsDisplayNone` will return `false`, if any of the elements in the passed in array has `display` other than `none`.

```
const areAllDivsDisplayNone = (divs) => {
  let allDisplayNone = true;
  for (let i in divs) {
    if (divs[i].style.display !== 'none') {
      allDisplayNone = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return allDisplayNone;
};

const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.a'));
const results = areAllDivsDisplayNone(els);

if (results) {
  console.log('Results!');
} else {
  console.log('No results!');
}
```

I made my code example a bit more verbose, so it's easier to read.